# FastAPI keyerror on class

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, fastapi, pydantic

I am trying to implement a put api using fastAPI. This is what I have done so far.

```
@router.put("/api/releases")
def put_release(response: schemas.ReleasePutSchema, id: int, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    release = db.query(Release).filter(Release.id == id)
    if not release.first():
         raise HTTPException
    response = jsonable_encoder(response)
    release.update(response)
    db.commit()
    return "updated"
```

Below is the schemas.py code.

```
from sa2schema.to.pydantic import sa_model
ReleaseGetSchema = sa_model(model.Release)
ReleasePutSchema = sa_model(model.Release, exclude=("id",), make_optional=True)
```

and this is the model.py

```
class Release(_ORMBase):
     id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
     name = Column(String, nullable=False)
     description = Column(String)
     comments = Column(String)
```

The get and the post apis which i have implemented earlier are working fine. But after setting the code like above for put apis, on loading the swagger UI, its throws me internal server error, **keyerror: class release**. But the strange thing is , if I write a write a class exactly similar to Release, lets say Putrelease and pass it to schema, it works. What could be the issue. How do I solve it.

Comment: How are you importing the class `Release` in the file that you have the route?

Comment: just importing it from the folder where it is stored like  - 
from folder.model import Release

Comment: Could you please post the whole stack trace that shows up in the terminal when the exception occurs?